# Add / Update custom object dictionaries array in swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary with custom object in swift.
Now I am comparing the object for add & update.
The logic is as simple to add the data if not exist and update if any change in dictionary.

User is custom object type:

```
 @objc public class User: NSObject , Mappable
```

from the getUserID i can able to get userID

The below code is execute in for loop from where i am passing User object.

```
 var peopleList = [User]()

if self.peopleList.count > 0 {
    if self.peopleList.contains(where: {$0.getUserID() == users.getUserID()})
    {
        // check for any update in dist
        if let index = self.peopleList.index(of: users)
        {
            if users.isEqual(self.peopleList[index])
            {
                print("equal no updates")
            }
            else 
            {
                print("need to updates objects..")
            }
        }        
        //already exist room
    }
    else
    {
        self.peopleList.append(users)
    }
}
```

I know it may be related to equatable

so I am using below fuction

```
func isEqual<T: Equatable>(type: T.Type, a: Any, b: Any) -> Bool? {
    guard let a = a as? T, let b = b as? T else { return nil }
    return a == b
}
```

But I am getting `index = nil.`
Is there any idea or suggestion to solve it.
If any other way to do it efficiently them most welcome.

Comment: Please add the relevant code what `peopleList`, `getUserID()` and `users` are. By the way, never, never, never check for empty array with `foo.count > 0` in Swift. There is more efficient property `!foo.isEmpty`. In most cases you can replace `contains(where` directly with `index(where` which is more efficient anyway.

Comment: Pleas try this if let index = self.peopleList.index(of: $0).

Comment: @Gigi $0 will not work because it is inside contains block.

Comment: Instead of doing `contains(where:)` followed by `index(of:)` why not just use `first(where:)`?

Comment: the code is executing inside for loop.

Comment: The code is extremely inefficient. You are checking the same condition three times. Once again the question cannot be answered satisfyingly without knowing the types and contents of `peopleList`, `getUserID()` and `users`.

Comment: There's still too few information: What is the difference between the `userID` check and the `isEqual` check? Is there any at all?

Comment: where are you getting users from??

Comment: From API Json i am converting to cusome object using ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this simplified version should work

```
if self.peopleList.isEmpty, let user = self.peopleList.first(where: { $0.getUserID() == users.getUserID() }) {
    if user == users {
        // is equal
    } else {
        // do update
    }
} else {
    self.peopleList.append(users)
}
```

Comment: it gives me "Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure"

Comment: @guru There is a pair of {} missing, I'll update the answer.